# Simple program "Syntax Error"

Tags: python

```
#this is my very first python attempt

print ("Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!")
original = raw_input("Word to translate:")

if len("string") > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

This is my entire code. Pretty darn simple, right? However, I get a Syntax Error when I try to run it. What is wrong? Do I need to start the code with something else?

Comment: If this concerns the two last `print` statements, use parentheses like in the first one. Also what is supposed to achieve `if len("string") > 0`? It returns the length of the string "string", which will always be > 0.

Comment: First I got "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" but after adding parentesis, I get 
'Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\python\test.py", line 4, in (module)
        original = raw_input("word to translate:")
NameError: name "raw_input" is not defined'

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @RheannaLamph use `input` in py3x instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: indeed, this is the issue

Comment: Yeah, Rheanna, if you're reading a Python2 manual and running a Python3 interpreter, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Yeah... I think I need to correct that.... haha

Answer (score 5):

I guess you're using py3.x and `print` is a function in py3.x.

Secondly `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in py3.x.

```
print ("Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!")
original = input("Word to translate:")
if len("string") > 0:
    print (original)
else:
    print ("empty")
```

Comment: ok, so I learned on an earlier version then... can I download one that still does use raw_input?

Comment: @RheannaLamph Yes, why not : http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/
Note that `print` is a statement is py2.x.

Comment: Better to use Python 3 if you don't need Python 2 for something.